# How does this term $e^{i\Phi_0}$ get removed in bloch sphere equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

A qubit can be represented in the form of
$$|\psi\rangle=\alpha|0⟩+\beta|1\rangle$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers. Or a complex number can be expressed by $R e^{i\Phi_0}$.
so the equation above will become 
$$|\psi\rangle=R_0e^{i\Phi_0}|0\rangle+R_1e^{i\Phi_1}|1\rangle.$$

Taking  $e^{i\Phi_0}$ as a common,
$$|\psi\rangle = e^{i\Phi_0} [R_0|0\rangle + R_1 e^{i(\Phi_1 - \Phi_0)}|1\rangle]$$

How  can this term $e^{i\Phi_0}$ be removed?

(I read online about it and I only found that it doesn't have an observable effect and it won't make any difference, but that doesn't make sense.

if we continue, 
$$|\psi\rangle =  [R_0|0\rangle + R_1 e^{i(\Phi_1 - \Phi_0)}|1\rangle],    \Phi_1 - \Phi_0 = \Omega .$$ 
or the sum of probabilities = 1
so $$|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$$
$$R_0^2 + R_1^2 = 1$$ we can deduce that $R_0 = \cos\frac{\Delta}{2}$ and $R_1 = \sin\frac{\Delta}{2}$

$$|\psi\rangle =  \cos\frac{\Delta}{2} |0\rangle +  e^{i\Omega} \sin\frac{\Delta}{2} |1\rangle,$$
Bloch Sphere equation

Comment: "I read online about it and I only found that it doesn't have an observable effect and it won't make any difference, but that doesn't make sense." - Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: observable effect on what exactly ?
i just want an explanation how that term got removed

Comment: A global phase doesn't have an observable effect on measurements. For example, the expectation value of any operator $A$ is given by $\langle\Psi|A|\Psi\rangle$. If we add a global phase $e^{i\theta}$ to $|\Psi\rangle$, then taking the conjugate transpose of this state gives us $e^{-i\theta}\langle\Psi|$, so we now have $e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}\langle\Psi|A|\Psi\rangle$. The two phases cancel out, no matter what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ket vector $|\Psi\rangle$ corresponds to a state of a quantum system, then $e^{i\theta}|\Psi\rangle$ corresponds to **exactly the same state**.  Put a different way, states are only defined up to a *global* phase factor, so we are free to drop the factor $e^{i\Phi_0}$ while remaining comfortable with the knowledge that we haven't changed the state.

If this makes you uncomfortable, then you are more than welcome to keep it; it will just mean a bunch of extra writing for you, and when it comes time to actually make a measurable prediction (e.g. finding the expected value of some operator), you will find that it cancels out anyway.